# Do we link (in speech) between 2 stressed words in a sentence?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, see this word "**good**" `/ɡʊd/` & this word "**idea**" `/aɪˈdɪə/`

Ok, now if we have a phrase "**I have a good idea**" `/aɪ həvə ɡʊd aɪˈdɪə/`, then which of the followings are right and which are wrong:

1. Link `/d/` & `/aɪ/` even both "**good**" & "**idea**" are stressed words in that sentence
2. Link `/d/` & `/aɪ/` if `/aɪ/` is not a stressed syllable even both "**good**" & "**idea**" are stressed words in that sentence.
3. Link `/d/` & `/aɪ/` only if "**good**" is a stressed word & "**idea**" is not a stressed word in that sentence.
4. DO NOT Link `/d/` & `/aɪ/` if "**good**" is not a stressed word & "**idea**" is a stressed word in that sentence.
5. Link `/d/` & `/aɪ/` if both "**good**" & "**idea**" are unstressed words in that sentence.

Other example, "*You got a cool eyebrow*" "`/... kuːl ˈaɪ.braʊ.../`". In this case, `/ˈaɪ/` is a stressed syllable, then should it becomes `/kuːˈlaɪ.braʊ/`. If that is the case then the listener may misunderstand

Comment: I think English language learners stress stress too much.  Stress comes naturally, from the flow of the syllables and the natural emotions you attach to them (or not, as the case may be).  Unless you're trying to create a computer app that speaks, you're better off not worrying about stress but instead just trying to get the pronunciations correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a bit annoyed that I keep getting a little confused, in the muddled assortment of enunciations and stressed words or syllables, so I found a great source to help with word connecting and so forth. You may already be familiar with it, as it's one of the first results on google when searching for "linking in speech."

linkingphonetics.wordpress.com

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Please take the pertinent information from the resource and quote it in your answer.